# Facebook Information

Tags: facebook, account-management, account-recovery, facebook-account

A new feature that permits downloading our Facebook information seems to be a very interesting feature, but I have a question:

If we download our information, and after that my Facebook account was hacked and stolen, can I make a new account and enter the information I have downloaded before so I can retrieve a same account as the old one. Because having a lot friends and then losing the account will make it difficult to remember all the friends and pages when we open a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you believe your account is hacked, check the [Hacked Accounts](https://www.facebook.com/help/131719720300233/) section of the Facebook Help Center to get immediate help.

If you are creating a new account, you can fill up the same information as your previous account but you have to fill all the section manually. And you need to send a new friend request to all your friends one by one. There is no automated way to replicate similar account using Facebook data from other account.